# Nginx - how to log an empty SSL connection with no request line

Tags: linux, nginx, ssl, ddos

We are currently under DDoS with the following vector: Attacker is establishing TLS connection then drop off.  (No request line is being sent)

This is causing serious CPU load on nginx cluser. We have ngnix as reverse proxy. I could not figure out a way how to make nginx to log a fact that such a connection was established to automate IP based bans.

All the logging stuff I found require request to be parsed but in this case there is no payload at all so nothing shows up in both access and error logs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log info;
```

You then see in the error log following:

```
2018/09/22 11:42:38 [info] 25066#25066: *343588460 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: ::1, server: [::]:443
```

And this behavior can be simulated via:

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect localhost:443
```